# VB.NET Unselect item in listbox when mouse click in empty field

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have a listbox (`mainlistbox`) that lists files in a specified directory. When I click them in the listbox I get a preview of the file in a richtextbox. This works perfectly, but I'm trying to figure out how to unselect an item in the mainlistbox when I mouse click in a empty field in the listbox.

`Mainlistbox selectedindexchanged` does thing like if file exists, file.readalltext to the textbox.

I'm now working on the event for mouse click on mainlistbox.

```
    Private Sub MainListBox_MouseClick(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles MainListBox.MouseClick

    If (MainListBox.SelectedIndex = -1) Then 'This is where I've tried "everything"
        MainListBox.ClearSelected()
end if
```

[image]

It seems to work before I got a item selected (tested using msgbox), but after I've selected one, I just can't unselect it. 
I've tried a bunch of variations, but I can't get it to work. Its probably something super simple that I've just not figure out yet. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can check on the mouse up if an item has been clicked, and if not clear your data:

```
Private Sub MainListBox_MouseUp(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles MainListBox.MouseUp
If MainListBox.IndexFromPoint(e.Location) < 0 Then
  ' clear the data
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @NDJ, that it exactly what I was looking for! :)